# Why does one simple CSV cleaning python script work but the other does't?

Tags: python, csv

I have the following CSV which contains junk characters in good data:

```
setA, setB, setC, setD, setE 
,1,text:u'GOOD DATA',BAD DATA:good.number,11.1 
,3,text:u'GOOD DATA',BAD DATA:good.number,11.2 
,5,text:u'GOOD DATA',BAD DATA:good.number,13.1 
,6,text:u'GOOD DATA',BAD DATA:good.number,11.5
```

After being cleaned it should look like this:

```
setA, setB, setC, setD, setE 
,1,GOOD DATA,BAD DATA:good.number,11.1 
,3,GOOD DATA,BAD DATA:good.number,11.2 
,5,GOOD DATA,BAD DATA:good.number,13.1 
,6,GOOD DATA,BAD DATA:good.number,11.5
```

I have a script with which I can successfully open the csv file, clean the data:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from sys import stdin

print(next(stdin) , end='')

for line in stdin:

    toks =[tok.replace("\'","").replace("text:u","").replace("number:", 
"") for tok in line.split()]

    print(' '.join(toks))
```

But I want to do it a different way, like this, using the csv function and DictReader:

```
rom __future__ import print_function
from sys import stdin
import csv

with open('./BROKENDATA.csv') as data:
    reader = csv.DictReader(data)
    for line in reader:
        toks = [tok.replace("\'","" 
).replace("text:u","").replace("number:", "") for tok in line.split()]
        print(' '.join(toks))
```

The second script throws an error: "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'"

I assume that this is because dict doesn't have the same functionality as what I was doing before. So A) why not, and B) how do I get the same functionality out of the second script?

Comment: `.split` is a string method, why do you imagine a `dict` would have `.split`? How would it *work*? What do you think `line.split()` **should do** in your second script? Presumably, you wanted to use `csv` to parse the csv... that is what is has done and put that row's data in a convenient dict for you.

Comment: You don't have to use `csv.DictReader()`, you can just use `csv.reader()`. Next time try debugging your script to see what you're trying to `split()`.

Comment: @Eqomatic then they would get `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: And I'm not asking these questions to lambast you. But you shouldn't be just adding lines to code you don't understand, and then expecting the code to work *exactly like it did before*. In your own mind, you should be asking yourself these sorts of questions when you write a line of code: "what does this do, what is the result, why am I doing it this way"?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I am getting there my friend. Learning more every day. Feedback like this is very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `line` from `reader` are dictionary type, you can access values from each column using column keys `setA, setB, setC, setD, setE` and edit them from there.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from sys import stdin
import csv

new_rows = []
with open('./BROKENDATA.csv') as data:
    reader = csv.DictReader(data)
    new_rows.append(','.join(reader.fieldnames))
    for line in reader:
        toks = [line['setA'], line[' setB'], line[' setC'].replace("text:u","").replace("\'", ""), line[' setD'], line[' setE ']]
        new_rows.append(','.join(toks)) 

with open('./BROKENDATA.csv', 'w') as f:
    for row in new_rows:
        f.write(row + '\n')
```

Here's what the `line` dictionary looks like:

```
{' setD': 'GOOD DATA:2.2', ' setE ': '11.1 ', 'setA': '', ' setC': "text:u'GOOD DATA'", ' setB': '1'}
```

Comment: Pretty close! Looks like this prints it to the console but doesn't actually update the source file. 

Also, I made a mistake on the CSV files. Looks like it is currently erasing the good number and leave the bad data.

Comment: I thought you want to print out the rows based on your given code. I've updated my answer so that it will store the cleaned rows in a list and will use them to update the source file after it finishes cleaning. I've also removed erasing the good number based on your new output.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('BROKENDATA.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
df['setC'] = df['setC'].str.replace('text:u','').str.replace('\'', '')
# OR df = df['setC'] = df['setC'].str[7:-1]
df.to_csv('BROKENDATA.csv', index=False)
```

The content of `BROKENDATA.csv` before running the code:

```
setA, setB, setC, setD, setE
,1,text:u'GOOD DATA',BAD DATA:good.number,11.1
,3,text:u'GOOD DATA',BAD DATA:good.number,11.2
,5,text:u'GOOD DATA',BAD DATA:good.number,13.1
,6,text:u'GOOD DATA',BAD DATA:good.number,11.5
```

Output:

```
setA,setB,setC,setD,setE
,1,GOOD DATA,BAD DATA:good.number,11.1
,3,GOOD DATA,BAD DATA:good.number,11.2
,5,GOOD DATA,BAD DATA:good.number,13.1
,6,GOOD DATA,BAD DATA:good.number,11.5
```